# How to know that there is an angle change while swiping?

Tags: android, swipe

am trying to add a swipe functionality in project . in this when user swipe over a particular character it will pick that letter and form the corresponding word. But my problem is i want to pick center character only when there is an angle change on center character while swapping like in the below image. Here I is the center character.
   [image]

Help please

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i searched  not able to find any solution , then i thought to pick the center character when the cirle is formed menes the no. of pixel count is larger than going straight , but it's not the efficient way to do .

Comment: @JoelFernandes you have any clue